# Combining multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
SubsID   SUMMARY        SP    Sprint_Name    cfname     SourceID
10547      AA           6.0   NULL           Points     10543
10547     AA            NULL  GOE 10/03     Sprint      10543
10547     AA            NULL  GO 10/17      Sprint      10543
```

I want the SP value to be displayed in the same row where the Sprint_Name is not NULL.
So I want my result to be like this

```
SubsID   SUMMARY        SP    Sprint_Name    cfname     SourceID
    10547     AA          6.0 GOE 10/03     Sprint      10543
    10547     AA          6.0  GO 10/17     Sprint      10543
```

Here is my query

```
Select ji.ID as SubsID, ji.SUMMARY,  it.pname as IssueType, 
     cfv.NUMBERVALUE as SP, sp.NAME as Sprint_Name,
     cf.cfname, ISNULL(il.SOURCE,ji.ID) as SourceID
     from
    jiraissue as ji
    inner join customfieldvalue as cfv on cfv.ISSUE = ji.ID
    left outer join issuelink as il on il.DESTINATION = ji.ID or il.SOURCE = ji.ID 
    left outer join customfieldoption as cfo on cast (cfo.ID as varchar(1000)) = cfv.STRINGVALUE
    left outer join AO_60DB71_SPRINT as sp on cast (sp.ID as varchar(1000)) = cfv.STRINGVALUE 
    left outer join customfield as cf on cf.ID = cfv.CUSTOMFIELD
```

The problem I am facing is SP and Sprint_Name come from different tables.
I thought of using Pivot function but that didnt work.
Here is the query with Pivot.

```
Select *
from 
( Select ji.ID as SubsID, ji.SUMMARY 
, cfv.NUMBERVALUE as SP, sp.NAME as Sprint_Name,
 cf.cfname, ISNULL(il.SOURCE,ji.ID) as SourceID
 from
jiraissue as ji
inner join issuestatus as st on ji.issuestatus = st.ID
inner join customfieldvalue as cfv on cfv.ISSUE = ji.ID
left outer join issuelink as il on il.DESTINATION = ji.ID or il.SOURCE = ji.ID 
left outer join customfieldoption as cfo on cast (cfo.ID as varchar(1000)) = cfv.STRINGVALUE
left outer join AO_60DB71_SPRINT as sp on cast (sp.ID as varchar(1000)) = cfv.STRINGVALUE 
left outer join customfield as cf on cf.ID = cfv.CUSTOMFIELD 
where  (il.LINKTYPE = 10200 or il.LINKTYPE is null) and it.pname <> 'Epic' 
) as SourceTable 
pivot
(max(SP)
for cfname IN ([Story Points])
) as PivotTable
```

The result I get is

```
SubsID  SUMMARY Sprint_Name SourceID    Story Points    
10547   AA      NULL        10543            6.0    
10547   AA      GO 10/17    10543           NULL
10547   AA      GOE 10/03   10543           NULL
```

Comment: What if there is more than one row that has a non-null SP value?

Comment: I will limit that using where clause. For a unique SubsID there will be only one row which has non null SP Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your regular query to get all the non-null SprintNames, and get SP with a sub-select.

pseudo-code:

```
SELECT SubsID, SprintName, SomeOtherColumns, 
  (SELECT TOP 1 SP FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.SubsID=t1.SubsID AND SP IS NOT NULL) AS StoryPoints
FROM MyTable t1
WHERE SprintName IS NOT NULL
```

In both places, replace "MyTable" with whatever collection of JOINs are needed to get the columns you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are a life saver, I apologize but I cant upvote your answer since I dont have enough reputation.